# Run grunt build command on Travis CI

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI to test and build my project and as part of it I want travis to run `grunt build` i have tried the following but have had no luck.

- `script: "grunt build"`
- `script: "./node_modules/grunt build"`
- `script: "./node_modules/grunt/grunt build"`
- `script: "./node_modules/grunt/grunt.js build"`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Have you made sure to install `grunt-cli` globally on your Travis node?

My Travis CI config looks like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.8"
before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install
before_script: grunt build
```

And my package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt test"
    },
    ...
}
```

I will explain the flow of steps that Travis will execute:

1. The first step to be executed is the `before_install`. My only prerequisite (besides node.js) is `grunt-cli` so I use this step to install it.
2. Next is the `install` step, in my case this will simply install my npm modules
3. The `before script` is then executed, running `grunt build`
4. Lastly Travis will look for scripts in the package.json, there I indicated the test step should run `grunt test`

I'd like to note that this is my own opinion on how to configure Travis. I'm certainly not inclining you should use exactly the same approach.

Comment: @Anzeo Should all other grunt task libraries required be part of devDependencies or dependencies? I noticed I still get build error saying "npm module not found", for instance, for "grunt-contrib-watch"

Comment: @theunexpected1 normally all your grunt tasks should be listed as development dependencies. Are you sure the contrib-watch is listed in the package.json?

Comment: @Anzeo, yeah, sure about that. I haven't gone much further to debug, for now, I have removed grunt build from the postinstall process. I'll get back once I try it again, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You likely miss in your travis.yml file:

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Then "grunt whatever" should execute ok (assuming you do require grunt in your devDependencies in your package.json).

(see http://www.mattgoldspink.co.uk/2013/02/10/using-travis-ci-with-grunt-0-4-x/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have grunt as part of your devDependencies. Here is a sample file: https://github.com/fraxedas/raspi-cloud/blob/master/package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
}
```

Travis-ci will install grunt on the install step:

```
npm install 
...
grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
...
```

In my case I wanted to run jshint with grunt.
Here is my travis.yml file: https://github.com/fraxedas/raspi-cloud/blob/master/.travis.yml

To integrate grunt all I needed was:

```
before_script: grunt jshint
```

You can change jshint by another command.

Answer (score 0):

My .travis.yml looks like this:

It runs much faster than `npm` as `NodeJS`package manager, I'm using `Yarn`on this example. It installs `yarn`, `grunt cli`, `ruby`and `sass`.

Hopefully it helps.

```
  language: node_js

  node_js:
    - "7.1.0"

  before_install:
    - npm install -g yarn
    - yarn add global ruby
    - gem install sass

  install:
    - yarn add global sass
    - yarn add global grunt-cli
    - yarn add yarn install

 before_script: grunt
```