# How to Continuously Deliver App Updates to the Chrome Store? Travis CI?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, travis-ci, continuous-delivery

I have a chrome app that I would like to automatically deploy to the Chrome App store as a part of my continuous delivery pipeline...

Is there a way to do this with Travis CI?

Does Travis provide a way to upload a zipped artifact to the chrome store?

Is it possible to build such functionality using a cli for the chrome store?

Comment: Does the answer below, from Alex, actually work? See my comment there about getting refresh tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) task using [grunt-webstore-upload](https://github.com/c301/grunt-webstore-upload) module and [run it from Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128478/run-grunt-build-command-on-travis-ci)

Sample Gruntfile.js:

```
var archiveName = "buildExt.zip";
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        webstore_upload: {
            "accounts": {
                "default": { //account under this section will be used by default
                    publish: true, //publish item right after uploading. default false
                    client_id: "xxx",
                    client_secret: "yyy",
                    refresh_token: "zzz"
                }
            },
            "extensions": {
                "myExtensionName": {
                    //required
                    appID: "aaa",
                    publish: true,
                    //required, we can use dir name and upload most recent zip file
                    zip: "build/" + archiveName
                }
            }
        }
    }),

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webstore-upload');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['webstore_upload']);
};
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Don't you need a refresh token - and on a headless travis CI, how does it get the refresh token?